# How to list all available entity types?

Tags: drush, entities

How to list all available entity types in Drupal using drush?

Related:

- [How to get list of all node types?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/3723/28275)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

#### Drupal 7

```
drush eval "print_r(array_keys(entity_get_info()));"
```

#### Drupal 8

```
drush eval "print_r(array_keys(\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getDefinitions()));"
```

<sup>as per [Jason suggestion](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/127939/how-to-list-all-available-entity-types/127940?noredirect=1#comment265834_127940)</sup>,

or:

```
drush eval "print_r(array_keys(\Drupal::entityManager()->getDefinitions()));"
```

<sup>as per [@RaisinBranCrunch suggestion](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/127939/how-to-list-all-available-entity-types/127940?noredirect=1#comment286393_127940). Note `\Drupal::entityManager()` is being deprecated in 8.x.</sup>

Comment: For Drupal 8, drush eval "print_r(array_keys(\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getDefinitions()));"

Comment: For me it has to be `drush eval "print_r(array_keys(\Drupal::entityManager()->getDefinitions()))";`

Comment: use  Cpas E instead of e in EntityManager.     drush eval "print_r(array_keys(\Drupal::EntityManager()->getDefinitions‌​()))";   entityManager  is depricated

Comment: `entityManager` is deprecated on latest versions of d8, use `entityTypeManager` for newer versions

Comment: If you want to list specifically content/config types use this: drush eval "print_r(\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getDefinitions());" | grep ContentEntityType (or ConfigEntityType for config entities)

Answer (score 15):

#### Drupal 8

Use the drupal console command:

```
drupal debug:entity
```

or (short hand):

```
drupal de
```

This will produce a concise list of entities available in *your* instance.

Comment: The OP says specifically "Using Drush"

Comment: drush eval 'system("drupal de");'  

Comment: Thanks @diamondsea 

Comment: Added bonus with console is to see if it's a content or configuration entity.

Answer (score 5):

You can create a drush command named `entities-list`. Create a module, put inside a file named `drush_entity.drush.inc` and paste this code:

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * Drush commands related to Entities.
 */

/**
* Implements hook_drush_command().
*/
function drush_entity_drush_command() {
  $items['entities-list'] = array(
    'description' => dt("Show a list of available entities."),
    'aliases' => array('el'),
  );
  return $items;
}

/**
 * Callback for the content-type-list command.
 */
function drush_drush_entity_entities_list() {
  $entities = array_keys(entity_get_info());
  sort($entities);

  drush_print(dt("Machine name"));
  drush_print(implode("\r\n", $entities));
}
```

Install the module, run `drush cc drush` to clear the drush cache and use the command like this:

```
drush el
```

or

```
drush entities-list
```

If you want add another alias to the command add elements to the aliases array like this:

```
'aliases' => array('el', 'another'),
```

And you can use this commands:

```
drush el
drush entities-list
drush another
```

Always the output will be:

```
Machine name:
entity 1
entity 2
entity...
entity n
```

**EDIT:**

There is another solution using the [Drush Entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/drush_entity) module:

```
drush entity-type-read
```

Comment: Another downvoter that don't says what's the problem with the answer just hit the downvote button. But if you don't says what's the problem I can't fix it.